# When viewed on a tablet, the very top navigation bar has no margin

Tags: bug, design

I'm talking about the Community, Ask, Developer, Design, etc. bar. When viewed on a tablet, the entire bar is shifted to the left of the screen, so that it has no margin, is directly against the edge, and has an empty white space at the right. Probably a small CSS fix.

This issue is reproducible on Server Fault except with the Stack Exchange bar instead of the Ubuntu bar.

[image: Screenshot of issue]

The arrow points to the missing margin. Please excuse the mspaint-edited photo.

Comment: Don't forget the gap on the right side too, also this happens on my android tablet.

Comment: @mateo the entire thing is offset on your android?

Comment: looks exactly like your picture. looks like just the top bar is offset?

Comment: Yeah, seems like it. I'm editing the question. Also, this happens to me on Server Fault too.

Comment: hm, looks like one to take to Meta SO, I viewed some other stack sites and many have the same or similar prolbem.

Comment: is it better on your ipad? it looks fixed on my tablet

Comment: Seems to be ok now.